# startapp in pydev

Tags: django, eclipse, pydev

Hi everyone i want to  To write a Django view for the main page, and i know that first i need to create a Django application inside my project. I know that i should write the following:   $ python manage.py startapp name , in a coomand line but my problem is that i don't know how can i do this into the pydev(eclipse). Does anybody knows?

```
 $ python manage.py startapp name
 filename contains-> __init__
                  ->forms
                  ->models
                  ->tests
                  ->views
```

Comment: Just run startapp from the command line... it's not going to stop you from using pydev afterwards.

Comment: This post shows how to do that in Eclipse PyDev with a lot of images depicting each step http://lowcoupling.com/post/47845431628/creating-a-new-django-project-with-eclipse-py-dev

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After creating a Django project inside PyDev, you should be able to right-click the project and select the `Django` entry for Django related actions... one of those is `Create application (manage.py startapp)`, which may be used to create the Django application.

Check: http://pydev.org/manual_adv_django.html if you need more info on setting an existing project as a Django project or creating the actual project.

Comment: Actually, the aforementioned manual doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Well, it should... anyways, it's something as Ctrl+2, dj and then enter the action you want (i.e.: startapp)

Comment: The title of the question is misleading. He does not want to start application within eclipse but a create a new application in eclipse. It is unfortunate that the command for it is called as "startapp" instead of something like "createapp". The answer of foki is correct in this context.

Comment: I've improved the wording (the manual does show that context menu and using `ctrl+2, dj` from an open editor in that project and then 'startapp` also works, but I've clarified the answer to reflect where to find the actual menu).

Comment: Thanks guys, with your help I found what I did not understand... and it was simpler then using the command line...

Answer (score 14):

Right click on project root -> Django -> Create application (manage.py startapp).

Comment: Either this one or Sindico's comment should be the accepted answer, in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks, with your help I found what I did not understand... and it was simpler then using the command line...